# how to crop image in matlab using only for loop?

Tags: matlab

i made it with Matrix.how can i make it with for loop

```
crop.m
function s=crop(f,m,n,x,y)
s=f(x:x+m,y:y+n);
```

[image]

Comment: _Why_ would you want to replace the simple, elegant, idiomatic Matlab statement `s=f(x:x+m,y:y+n);` by a loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is code

```
crop1.m

function s=crop1(f,m,n,x,y)

for i=x:1:x+m
      for j=y:1:y+n 
                s(i-x+1,j-y+1,:)=f(i,j,:);              
      end
end
```